# Google Chrome forces download of PHP scripts' source

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, google-chrome

I'm experiencing a behaviour of Google Chrome (Google Chrome 7.0.517.41 beta) that I can't understand. In some cases, Google Chrome *downloads* the *source code* of the PHP script that is requested from my server instead of it being executed. I don't have this problem with cURL or Firefox; when I request the same URL with them the script is executed properly.

This seems to me rather odd because I this should be a server issue and it should work the same in every browser. I think I must have overlooked something or Google Chrome is sending some unusual HTTP headers... I don't know. I've checked `AddHandler` and `AddType` directives in Apache configuration files with no success. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Link to pages where this happens ?

Comment: This is an issue on my development server which is currently not public so I can't give any links.

Comment: If you can actually download the source, it is definitely a bug in the webserver, and not related to user-agent (or only related in that a certain request can trigger an error condition in the webserver itself, which should never happen, and is still a problem of the webserver). Check apache error logs, and if you cannot find any problems there, I'd just go for a reinstall, as I wouldn't trust the current setup at any level anymore.

Comment: Yes, I know there is a problem in the webserver but it must be caused by something in Google Chrome's requests. I've checked error.log and it looks perfectly fine. So you propose to re-install Apache or something else as well?

Comment: How do the request headers send by Chrome differ from those sent by FireFox?

Comment: Also, what version of Chome are you running? I'm currently seeing the same for Perl/CGI in production environment - FF fine, Chrome downloads Perl source, worked fine at least a month ago.

Comment: @Jon Cram: Is there any straightforward way to log the request headers used in these browsers?

Comment: Download Microsoft Fiddler and set it as proxy for the browsers you wish to test (note: it sets itself as proxy automatically for IE and FF).

Comment: jindrichm: I use the LiveHttpHeaders addon and/or Firebug for FF. For Chrome, open the developer tools and go to Resources. That doesn't provide logging but it does let you see what headers were sent. I have seen that Chrome can be over keen on caching and this can cause the problem to persist long after it's been fixed - a reinstall of Chrome sorted my problem yesterday.

Comment: @Jon Cram: Thanks for the suggestion to investigate the Google Chrome's cache. I've cleared it and it solved the issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution for this issue was to clear the Google Chrome's cache which seems to hold some data cached for too long. It was probably wrong on the server as it was sending raw PHP code previously but due to caching this issue persisted for Google Chrome even after it was fixed.

Thanks to [Jon Cram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343/jon-cram) for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks!  Seems like chrome really keeps stuff around for a while.