# Chrome wants to download index.php

Tags: apache, google-chrome, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome forces download of PHP scripts' source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949086/google-chrome-forces-download-of-php-scripts-source)

I'm working on Ubuntu 11.04 with Apache2 and PHP 5.3.5.

In my document root, I have two files: a test.php printing phpinfo() and index.php for a fresh download of CodeIgniter 2.0.2

When I try to visit index.php using chrome (11.0.696.57, not Chromium), it tries to download the file. When I visit test.php using Chrome, it displays the file correctly.

When I visit these files with Firefox 4.0 on the same machine, they are BOTH displayed correctly.

Anyone else dealt with this before?

It cannot be a permissions issue as FF displays the files correctly with application type text/html.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949086/google-chrome-forces-download-of-php-scripts-source apparently describes the same problem.

Comment: That did it! Can you please add it as an answer so I can give you the karma you deserve good Sir! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949086/google-chrome-forces-download-of-php-scripts-source) apparently describes the same problem, it's apparently cache related.

Answer (score 0):

Your page should probably return 'Content-type: text/html' at the start (followed by a newline). Your webserver otherwise doesn't know if an image, or text or some movie is getting generated by your php script.

Comment: It is. If I check the headers using Firebug on FF for both index.php and test.php - both have Content-type: text/html'. Using Chrome dev tools, test.php shows Content-type: text/html, but for index.php, the download prompt is shown which the content-type field is blank for the GET request

Comment: Can you post index.php somewhere?

Comment: There was NOTHING wrong with my index.php, it was freshly unzipped from the CodeIgniter 2.0.2 zip file. The caching issue solved it. Thanks.